# Forcing straight AND orthogonal edges with dot

Tags: graph-theory, graphviz, dot, orthogonal, edge-list

I have a program that automatically generates dot graphs representing the structure of a system. The system is defined by the user using a set of equations.

I would like to force dot displaying only straight **and** orthogonal edges between nodes. The placement of the nodes can be anywhere as long these two requirements are met.

For example, I want to prevent the edge corners that the following code generates:

```
digraph R {

  graph [splines=ortho, nodesep=1]
  node [shape=record];

   rA -> sA;
   sA -> vB;
   t  -> rA;
   uB -> vB;
   wB -> u;
   wB -> tA;

}
```

[image]

I found that one way to achieve this is by using the `rank` attribute. For example:

```
digraph R {

  graph [splines=ortho, nodesep=1]
  node [shape=record];

  { rank=same rA sA tA }
  { rank=same uB vB wB }


   rA -> sA;
   sA -> vB;
   t  -> rA;
   uB -> vB;
   wB -> u;
   wB -> tA;

}
```

[image]

However, using the `rank` attribute does not solve my problem since it would be very difficult to automate this for *any* graph. The logic for assigning ranks (which influences the node placement) to every node would be extremely complex (the graphs can become quite large). I want to know if there is another way of obtaining this output that does not require the use of the `rank` attribute.

Comment: Welcome please supply the details. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I rephrased the question. Hopefully, it's more clear now.